# ConcurrentHashMap throws recursive update exception

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

Here is my Java code:

```
static Map<BigInteger, Integer> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

static Integer minFinder(BigInteger num) {
        if (num.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (num.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            //focus on stuff thats happening inside this block, since with given inputs it won't reach last return
            return 1 + cache.computeIfAbsent(num.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2)),
                    n -> minFinder(n));
        }
        return 1 + Math.min(cache.computeIfAbsent(num.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), n -> minFinder(n)),
                cache.computeIfAbsent(num.add(BigInteger.ONE), n -> minFinder(n)));
    }
```

I tried to memoize a function that returns a minimum number of actions such as division by 2, subtract by one or add one.
The problem I'm facing is when I call it with smaller inputs such as:

```
minFinder(new BigInteger("32"))
```

it works, but with bigger values like:

```
minFinder(new BigInteger("64"))
```

It throws a Recursive Update exception.
Is there any way to increase recursion size to prevent this exception or any other way to solve this?

Comment: According to the docs, a recursive update exception implies you're making one entry in the map have a value that depends on itself, which is impossible to define.  Consider logging the values of `num` you're working on to try to trace where that happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the API docs of `Map.computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)):

> The mapping function should not modify this map during computation.

[The API docs of `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) make that stronger:

> The mapping function **must not** modify this map during computation.

(Emphasis added)

You are violating that by using your `minFinder()` method as the mapping function.  That it seems nevertheless to work for certain inputs is irrelevant.  You need to find a different way to achieve what you're after.

> Is there any way to increase recursion size to prevent this exception or any other way to solve this?

You could avoid `computeIfAbsent()` and instead do the same thing the old-school way:

```
BigInteger halfNum = num.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
BigInteger cachedValue = cache.get(halfNum);

if (cachedValue == null) {
    cachedValue = minFinder(halfNum);
    cache.put(halfNum, cachedValue);
}
return 1 + cachedValue;
```

But that's not going to be sufficient if the computation loops.  You could perhaps detect that by putting a sentinel value into the map before you recurse, so that you can recognize loops.